# Jira Mattermost Integration

Tags: jira, mattermost

I am having hard time integrating Jira and Mattermost. After configuring Webhook in mattermost and Jira, I get HandleIncomingWebhook code=400 error in mattermost log. And, JIRA (Beta) integration in mattermost does not post anything to mattermost. Am I missing anything? I used below mentioned link to configure Jira (Beta) with mattermost.
https://docs.mattermost.com/integrations/jira.html

Comment: What port you are using to Run your Mattermost on? Default Port?

Comment: @SalehParsa, It is in default port. Should I use different port other than default?

Comment: Well try with port 80! I have seen similar problem last week, so move it to port 80 and see if it works after that or not.

Comment: Hi @SalehParsa, sorry I just got chance looking at the issue recently. I changed the port to 80 from 8065, I believe it is the ListenAddress in config.json file if I am not wrong. However, I still have the same problem. I followed mattermost website to configure the server. Please let me know where did you change the port 80!. Thanks.